# divide data in sql to groups order by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this set of data

```
shopId companyId   date
1        1         25/8/2015
2        1         26/8/2015
3        1         22/8/2015
4        2         20/8/2015
5        2         27/8/2015
```

what i need is to get this result

```
shopId companyId   date        dense_rank
1        2         27/8/2015       1
2        2         20/8/2015       1
3        1         26/8/2015       2
4        1         25/8/2015       2
5        1         22/8/2015       2
```

how to get all groups ranked but order with date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the groups ordered by date, then you need two steps:  first get the maximum date for each group.  Then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select shopid, companyid, date,
       dense_rank() over (order by maxd desc) as dense_rank
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by companyid) as maxd
      from table t
     ) t
```

Note:  this assumes that your date is really stored as a date and not as a string.  You will need additional transformations if the data is (improperly) stored as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY companyId DESC, [Date] DESC) AS [DENSE_RANK]
FROM TableName
```

Comment: I think the order should be by date, not CompanyId

Comment: didn't pay much attention to the dates :)